# MobaXterm launches SCP not SFTP

Tags: sftp, scp, mobaxterm

I'm connecting to a remote Linux lab and need to be able to see all the directories on the side. It worked fine on my other computer. I noticed that the side tab that comes up is "SCP" when I think it should be "SFTP"
[My side bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1g99.png)

I have looked around and found answers saying to change the setting "Display SFTP browser". I can't find this setting. I found that on this question here...
[MobaXterm drag-and-drop panel missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893512/mobaxterm-drag-and-drop-panel-missing)

[This is what my settings look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNHeu.png)

[This is my session settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxpaH.png)

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).