# Can't upload files

Tags: file, upload, mobaxterm

I'm connecting to my university's servers with mobaxterm.
When I try to drag and drop a file, the loading screen shows it's 0%, and nothing seems to happen since.

Comment: How are you connecting to the servers? According to the online documentation, at https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html, you need to connect via ssh in order to use the ssh-browser to drag and drop files.

Comment: Don't have reputation to comment on **@Dharman's** post but feel it is worth adding that I also ran into this issue with a new university account and was able to solve this by closing and logging back in. When I logged back in I received feedback from the command line that said `There were 4 failed login attempts since the last successful login`. Spoiler alert, no one was hacking my account during this time, this was in fact my 4 failed attempts of uploading my data with the old credentials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have previously posted this as a comment for an answer, but I think it should be written as an answer, as it solved my problem.
The path where my file was saved was not in English. Mobaxterm does not recognize letters in a different language (not in Hebrew anyway).
Changed all path letters to English (on my computer of course) and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 28):

I had this problem too. Changing the file transfer protocol from SFTP to SCP solved it for me. From the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893512/mobaxterm-drag-and-drop-panel-missing#answer-49066986):

- Edit your session properties (MobaXTerm > Home > User sessions > your server > right-click > Edit session)
- SSH > Advanced SSH settings > SSH-browser type > SCP (I chose "enhanced speed", but you may need "normal speed")
- Restart your session

Comment: Restarting the session is required. Just wanted to highlight this for emphasis

Comment: I also want to add.. for me at least.. it works.. then  it doesn't.. then I mess with that setting.. doesn't matter what one it is on.. I pick a different one.  Sometimes ones I switched from SFTP to SCP stop working and I switch em back and they start working again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a entry about it in the log file:

1. Help
2. View MobaXTerm log file

Comment: Thanks!
apparently, my path was not in english.. Thats why it didnt upload 
thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but with another root cause.  Posting another answer in case this is useful to someone else.

In my case, my password had changed after the original ssh login to the terminal.  On a file upload MobaXTerm uses a cached copy of your password to connect via sftp, so the sftp upload was failing because of invalid credentials.  This login attempt failed silently, and just looked like the upload was paused at 0%.

Situation was resolved by closing the ssh terminal and attempting to open it again.  The ssh login attempt will fail (invalid password), MobaXTerm will ask for your new password, and will cache that one.  Subsequent file upload will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too when I was using a session that I had open before updating my university password!
The solution: If you recently updated your university password you need to update the password in Mobaxterm in order to connect to your account. Close all your sessions (windows open in Mobaxterm) first, then open a new session and it will ask you again for your current university password.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is just as [BenShephard solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55591215/15594254) except I had to change mine backwards, from SCP to SFTP. I guess it depends on your university policy what works and what doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same, upload was not working from my Window's desktop to the remote host. Moved files to one of the folders on D: drive and the problem was fixed