# Can't view, download, nor upload files on MobaXterm windows

Tags: mobaxterm

I connect to my university cluster on MobaXterm to submit jobs and when trying to download, upload, or open any files, they start but remain stuck at 0% progress

Its basically the same problem as this
[Can't upload files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602440/cant-upload-files)

But with all the features, upload, download, open file, and, also, none of the solutions worked for me. Changing to SCP didn't work, no problem with path file language.

MobaXterm log shows this after transfer begins:

```
 [22:18.35.214]  (SSH-Browser) TDownUpForm.Timer1Timer

[22:18.35.824]  (SSH-Browser) TDownUpForm.Timer1Timer

[22:18.36.434]  (SSH-Browser) TDownUpForm.Timer1Timer

[22:18.37.043]  (SSH-Browser) TDownUpForm.Timer1Timer
```

Keeps going until i cancel the transfer, no errors come up.